# Index Optimization

Tags: mysql, indexing

We always use index for DB optimization. But what is Index optimization. what are the challenge in indexing? Do we need a Index Optimization? How do we do that in mysql?

Is this dependent or independent of Mysql Engine Like InnoDB or Myisam?

Answer (score 1):

Find all your answers here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/table-of-contents

Some answers:

> But what is Index optimization.

I'd say it is making sure to have the right indexes (but no more) in place.

> what are the challenge in indexing

Obviously: finding the right indexes. That depends on the queries you are running. Basically you need to have an overview of all queries that hit your database to find the right indexes.

> This is independent of Mysql Engine Like InnoDB or Myisam.

Although indexing is generally not very sensitive to the database technology, MyISAM and InnoDB represent examples for the only difference that makes a big difference: while MyISAM uses so-called "heap" tables, InnoDB uses "clustered indexes". The details are explained in the link above, but here is an [article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key) just focusing on this particular difference.

As mentioned, this is the only major difference you need to care regarding indexing across different databases. Sure there are a lot of minor differences.